# $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin ( \frac{5^n + 2^n}{n!})$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I was trying to determine weather or not $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin ( \frac{5^n + 2^n}{n!})$ converges using perhaps the D'Alembert test, but it doesn't really seem to fit..are there other ways?

Comment: Please try to figure something on your own instead of flooding the site with almost trivial questions. $\frac{5^n}{n!}$ is summable (to $e^5$), so your series is converging.

Comment: For large $n$ you can ignore the term $2^n$ in the numerator, since its contribution is negligible compared to $5^n$. It is also easy to show that successive terms $5^n/n!$ decrease rapidly, namely by a factor $5/n$. So the argument of the $sin$-function rapidly goes to zero, and the sum converges.

Answer (score 6):

Using $\sin(x)<x$ for $x>0$ we have $$\left|\sin\left(\frac{5^n+2^n}{n!}\right)\right|<\frac{5^n+2^n}{n!}.$$
Thus $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{5^n+2^n}{n!}\right)$$ converges as $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5^n+2^n}{n!}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5^n}{n!} + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n!}=e^2+e^5-2.$$

Comment: I think you want to say $|\sin x|< x, x>0$ in the first line.

Comment: One can easily follow $|\sin(x)|<x,x>0$ from $\sin(x)<x,x>0$, but yes, that is what I'm using here.